# How to use ref?

Tags: c#, ref

I'm learning to use ref, but can't understand, why I'm getting an error?

```
class A
{
    public void ret(ref int variable)
    {
        variable = 7;
    }

    static int Main()
    {
        int z = 5;
        ret(ref z); // Error: Need a reference on object
        Console.WriteLine(z); // it will be 7 as I understand
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `ref` parameter. It's that `ret` is an instance method, and you can't call an instance method without a reference to an instance of that type.

Try making `ret` static:

```
public static void ret(ref int variable)
{
    variable = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using `ref` correctly. The error is actually because `ret()` is an *instance* method, while `Main()` is *static*. Make `ret()` static as well and this code will compile and work as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is not static.You need to make is static like this:

```
public static void ret(ref int variable)
{
    variable = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `ret` is an instance method you can't access it without creating an object of the type.

Try making the method `ret` as `static method` like `public static void ret(ref int variable)`